# Android Berkeley DB 11g Synchronization with Database Lite Mobile Server

Tags: android, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I am developing one Android database application.

I am planing to use newly released Oracle Berkeley DB 11g as my database in Android phone as it has automatic Synchronization feature with Database Lite Mobile Server.

I have implemented Berkeley DB in my Android application. Now I want some information how to Synch with Mobile Server. I am not getting much information regarding this.

Can anyone help to get a general idea how to Synch data between Android Berkeley DB and Mobile Server.

Thanks a lot..............

Answer (score 0):

My info is that Berkeley-JE does not work with Mobile Server.  The Mobile server only works with the SQLite SQL API.  You can use BDB (the C version), since it does have the SQLite API